# Exporting a range of keyframes to COLLADA

Tags: animation, keyframes, collada

I've imported mocap data to Blender to clean, and am now trying to break the animation into multiple COLLADA files. I have two strategies, but I don't know if they are possible.

1. Export a specific keyframe range - I don't see any option to do this
2. Cut a keyframe range and replace the entire animation with the range I want to export, and do this for each range - I'm not sure how to cut the entire animation

Are either of these possible?